# Completely clear/delete/erase/wipe/destroy a USB drive using the gpt command line utility?

Tags: partition, diskutil

I want to completely delete *all* GPT (meta)data off an USB drive, so I can create a fresh new GPT.
So I do:

`sudo gpt destroy disk3`

No errors, seems OK. However if I do:

`sudo gpt -r show disk3`

I get:

```
      start       size  index  contents
          0  245759967
  245759967         32         Sec GPT table
  245759999          1         Sec GPT header
```

So apparently there's still something left at the end of the drive. If I now do:

`sudo gpt create disk3`

I'm getting:

> gpt create: disk3: error: device already contains a GPT

How do I completely get rid of all partitioning structures or GPT index or metadata backup headers or whatever is still there, and completely re-create a new, clean GPT from scratch?

Comment: Try it with the `-r` flag so it ensures that the table cannot be recovered.

Comment: @Allan Tried that too, but made no difference. After `destroy -r` the Sec GPT table and header are still there. By the way I accidentally noticed that `man gpt` says "The -r option instructs gpt to destroy the table in a way that it can be recovered." I guess that's a typo and should be "can not". But either way, it didn't work with or without the -r.

Comment: Why not use `diskutil partitionDisk` function - that will most definitely destroy the GPT tables and write a new one with single command.

Comment: It's not pure `gpt`, but how about `dd`-ing `/dev/zero` to the drive for a few seconds before you use `gpt` to rebuild?: `sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/disk9` (change `disk9` to your drive ID of choice.

Comment: @Allen yes, thanks, that seems to do  something, although that also automatically creates a 200MB EFI partition and in this particular case I want to avoid that. I want a completely empty GPT drive, and only create two partitions manually (and no implicit EFI partition).

Comment: @PeteCooper Thanks! Yes that got rid of all partition structures completely. I can now do `sudo gpt destroy disk3` to create a brand new GPT. However, when I do so, it only creates the Primary GPT header and table, not the Secondary. This prevents me from manually creating partitions afterwards (using `gpt add`). It suggests to use `gpt recover`, but if I do so (i.e. `sudo gpt recover disk3`) it says it recovered the secondary GPT table and header from primary. However if I check with `sudo gpt -r show` it's really not there, still only the Primary ones. And I still can't do `sudo gpt add …` ?

Comment: @Allan coincidentally I noticed the `-r` flag for `destroy` does indeed mean destroy in a way it CAN be recovered (that's no typo in the manual). When I do the steps from my above comment (to Pete Cooper) and I have only a Primary table+header, then if I do `sudo gpt destroy -r disk3` it says "recoverability not possible". Apparently because the Secondary table+header is not there. It does successfully destroy everything without `-r` in this case.